# Forward email from account that has it blocked

Tags: gmail, gmail-imap

I have a school Google Apps account that has disabled the Gmail auto-forward feature. Is there any way to pull the emails down manually and forward it back up to my personal one?

Answer (score 1):

Using [Thunderbird](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/), setup to connect to two accounts, you can drag emails from one account to another.
Just select the emails you want to move, and drag and drop to your desired destination.

I don't remember if you can even define rules that will move the emails automatically between accounts.